# How to write below SQL query in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The below statement is in SQL code. How do I write it in BigQuery?

`select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')) from dual`

Comment: what do you mean by "big query" ? Provide corresponding links to the tools you are referring.

Answer (score 2):

As described in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

Try something like:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE()) as the_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y", CURRENT_DATE()) as current_year;
```